# getting array error in autocad vba. subscript out of range

Tags: vba, autocad, polyline, subscript

i am trying to create code which select polygons and tell what it contains i.e mtext.
but i am getting error while redim array.

below is the code for it. its giving subscript

```
Sub polycoords()
   Dim objSSet As AcadSelectionSet, a As AcadLWPolyline, objSSet1 As AcadSelectionSet, a1 As AcadMText, pointsArray() As Double, j As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim lngMode As Long, cc As Integer
    If Not objSSet Is Nothing Then
        objSSet.Delete
     End If
    Set objSSet = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.Add("443t39cr2t")

    objSSet.SelectOnScreen

     For Each a In objSSet



         ReDim pointsArray(0 To UBound(a.Coordinates) + UBound(a.Coordinates) / 2)
         j = 0
         For i = 0 To UBound(a.Coordinates) + UBound(a.Coordinates) / 2 Step 2
             pointsArray(j) = a.Coordinates(i)
             j = j + 1
             pointsArray(j) = a.Coordinates(i)
             j = j + 1
             pointsArray(j) = a.Coordinates(i)
             j = j + 1
         Next i

               Set objSSet1 = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.Add("g44c3rt2it")
               lngMode = acSelectionSetWindowPolygon

               objSSet1.SelectByPolygon lngMode, pointsArray
              For Each a1 In objSSet1
                  Debug.Print a1.TextString
              Next a1

         Debug.Print vbNewLine

         On Error Resume Next
     Next a
     If Not objSSet Is Nothing Then
        objSSet.Delete
     End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

the main issue in your code is that you don't properly handle the correct and different dimensions of the two arrays as per AutoCAD object nmodel

1) [LWPolyline `Coordinates`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2017/ENU/?guid=GUID-11CAC0D6-DFCF-4653-8403-CF5AFD689773) property returns an *"array of 2D points in OCS"* for LWPolylines

2) [`SelectByPolygon`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2017/ENU/?guid=GUID-D8002585-5D08-45E2-AF6C-6E894FA3D463) method accepts a *"three-element array of doubles"*

In the following code you can see those issues fixed along with some other coneptual flaws concerning the setting and use of `SelectionSet` objects (see explanatory comments):

```
Sub PolyCoords()
    Dim objSSet As AcadSelectionSet, objSSet1 As AcadSelectionSet
    Dim a As AcadEntity, a1 As AcadEntity ' you never know what the user is going to actually select, so use a "generic" type
    Dim myLWPoly As AcadLWPolyline ' use a specifically typed variable for the wanted object
    Dim pointsArray() As Double
    Dim j As Long, i As Long, lngMode As Long ' get in the habit of always using 'Long' type instead of 'Integer', to avoid overflow errors (integers reaches up to some 32 thousands)

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objSSet = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets("443t39cr2t") ' try gettin the selection set named after "443t39cr2t"
    On Error GoTo 0
    If objSSet Is Nothing Then Set objSSet = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.Add("443t39cr2t") ' if unsuccessful (i.e. there was no such SSet named after "443t39cr2t") then create it
    objSSet.Clear ' clear the selectionset

    objSSet.SelectOnScreen

    Dim nVert As Long ' variable to hold LWPlyline number of vertices
    lngMode = acSelectionSetWindowPolygon ' set 'SelectByPolygon' 'Mode' parameter using 'AcSelect' enumeration value
    For Each a In objSSet
        If TypeOf a Is AcadLWPolyline Then ' if current object in selectionset is a LWPolyline
            Set myLWPoly = a
            nVert = (UBound(myLWPoly.Coordinates) + 1) / 2 ' get the number of its vertices: for LWPolylines coordinates returns an "array of 2D points in OCS"
            ReDim pointsArray(0 To nVert * 3 - 1) ' dim the array for 'SelectByPolygon': it accepts a "three-element array of doubles"
            j = 0
            For i = 0 To nVert - 1
                pointsArray(j) = myLWPoly.Coordinates(i)
                j = j + 1
                pointsArray(j) = myLWPoly.Coordinates(i + 1)
                j = j + 1
                pointsArray(j) = 0 ' 3rd coordinate must be zero, since LWPolyline is a 2D element
                j = j + 1
            Next

            On Error Resume Next
            Set objSSet1 = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets("g44c3rt2it") ' try gettin the selection set named after "443t39cr2t"
            On Error GoTo 0
            If objSSet1 Is Nothing Then Set objSSet1 = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.Add("g44c3rt2it") ' if unsuccessful (i.e. there was no such SSet named after "443t39cr2t") then create it
            objSSet1.Clear ' clear the selectionset

            objSSet1.SelectByPolygon lngMode, pointsArray
            For Each a1 In objSSet1
                If TypeOf a1 Is AcadText Or TypeOf a1 Is AcadMText Then Debug.Print a1.TextString ' if current item in selectionset is a TEXT or MTEXT then type its text
            Next
            objSSet1.Clear ' clear the selectionset for subsequent use

            Debug.Print vbNewLine
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

of course you can decide to wrap the SelectionSet code block in a specific function, to avoid duplicating code, better maintain it and, hopefully, reuse it, like:

```
Function GetOrSetSelectionSet(ssetname As String) As AcadSelectionSet
    Dim objSSet As AcadSelectionSet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objSSet = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets(ssetname) ' try gettin the selection set named after passed variable 'ssetname'
    On Error GoTo 0
    If objSSet Is Nothing Then Set objSSet = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.Add(ssetname) ' if unsuccessful (i.e. there was no such SSet named after passed variable 'ssetname') then create it
    objSSet.Clear ' clear the selectionset

    Set GetOrSetSelectionSet = objSSet ' return the selectionset object
End Function
```

to be used in your main code as:

```
Set objSSet = GetOrSetSelectionSet("443t39cr2t") ' get or set a cleared selection set named after "443t39cr2t"
```

and

```
Set objSSet1 = GetOrSetSelectionSet("g44c3rt2it") ' get or set a cleared selection set named after "g44c3rt2it"
```

instead of those code blocks of five statements each

Comment: thanks for your reply but the code actually returning nothing.....and off cource with no error. can you  please fix it

Comment: I testetd it myself before answering. So you test it by stepping through the code (place the cursor in any place of the code and press F8, and the press F8 to step to next statement) and querying relevant variables in Immediate window (CTRL-G to pop it out and the type anything like, for instance, `?j` and press enter)

Answer (score 0):

pointsArray must be Variant type.
Additionally, you may not get the results you expect without zooming the selection.